# Deploy WSO2 Governance Registry on an application server?

Tags: deployment, wso2

In the [installation instructions](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Installing+on+Linux+and+Solaris) of WSO2 Governance Registry there is no mentioning of installing the product on an application server.

However, as I understand it WSO2 Governance Registry is running on WSO2 Carbon. Is that right?

For WSO2 Carbon I found this article on how to run it on an application server: [How Stuff Works – WSO2 Carbon](http://wso2.com/library/articles/stuff-works-wso2-carbon).

Would you recommend to run WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 on an application server, i.e. not only running as a bundle? Specifically I am wondering about the application server JBOSS EAP 6.x. Is there any instructions for such installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, All the WSO2 products  are running on top carbon.. 
Regarding on, running WSO2 products in other containers like in Jbos.. It is not recommended because that might cause many complications in many aspects.. I think From WSO2 Carbon platform 4.0.0 release onwards there is no any official support for hosting WSO2 products on third party containers.

And FYI WSO2 containers are itself secure enough for enterprise requirement..

Answer (score 1):

A WSO2 Product is basically WSO2 Carbon Kernel + Set of Features.

There is an [article](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/wso2-governance-registry-3-0-1-deployment-jboss-5-1-0-ga-oracle-10g) explaining how to deploy WSO2 Governance Registry on JBoss. But that's for an older version.

As you have mentioned in the question, the [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/stuff-works-wso2-carbon) explains how to run WSO2 Carbon on other application servers, but it is no longer recommended and not tested.

AFAIK it is strongly recommended to run the WSO2 Products in standalone mode.